# Is it safe to do two consecutive jumps in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new to assembly language and it is going well for me, however, a question has got my mind, as long as the result of a comparison is stored in `%eflags` register, can I put two consecutive conditional jumps and expect the result I want?

**Example:**

```
cmpl %eax, %ebx
je label1
jl label2      # Is this safe? Is this the right way to do this?
```

Comment: is it safe, yes.  Is it the right or wrong way to do this?  Sometimes it can be done in fewer instructions, you have to understand the flags, and unsigned vs signed affect on the flags (Then you can choose the right conditional branch).

Comment: Jumps don't generally affect `%eflags`, so this is fine, at least from the standpoint of doing the expected thing. In fact, you can use as many conditional instructions as you want after a comparison/arithmetic operation/etc. until the next instruction that actually does modify `%eflags`. However, the above may not be the most cache-friendly or efficient method...

Comment: You even can save and load flags using `lahf`,`sahf` to be able to continue your conditional jumping :)

Comment: @dwelch, please put your comment as an answer so I would accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is it safe, yes. Is it the right or wrong way to do this? Sometimes it can be done in fewer instructions, you have to understand the flags, and unsigned vs signed affect on the flags (Then you can choose the right conditional branch).

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely legal in x86 assembly, and often very useful. However: 
On some x86 micro-architectures, executing two or more consecutive branch instructions would cause a pipeline flush, costing ~15 processor cycles every time. On such processors, care has to be taken not to branch to a jump, and to put `NOPS` between consecutive jumps. The latest few generations of x86's handle this situation more gracefully, but if the code is supposed to run on older machines this should be taken into account.
For more complex control flow, switch cases (in high level languages) can be implemented by jump tables, using fewer conditional jumps.